# Installing only Ubuntu on a Vista/Ubuntu PC with separate hard drives

Tags: installation, removing

I installed a 160GB hard drive D: and installed Ubuntu on that drive using Windows installer (WUBI). I am running Vista on the C:drive (320 GB) and am using dual boot to access either Ubuntu or Vista when I boot up. I have recently purchased a Windows 8 PC (Grrr!) but under the circumstancs do not want or need the VISTA operating system on the other PC. What I would like to do is the following: 
1. Transfer all my files to the Win 8 PC
2. Switch the 160 GB drive to be my C:drive and the 320 GB Drive to be my d:drive
3. install Ubuntu 12 on the 'new' c: drive and use the D: drive for files and programs

On the original install of Ubuntu, I partitioned the 160 GB drive for U9.04 but it is all tied to dual boot and was done through WUBI. I'm sure new versions of Ubuntu will require different partitioning setups anyway.If I could I would like to just clean everything out and start from scratch. I run free programs mostly, but anything I need like printers Web Cams, Router, etc. I have software for. As far as personal data I can save everything off to external drives and reload later as needed.

I don't know if I can just wipe both hard drives clean, then reset my BIOS to recognize the 'new' drive setup, then start installing Ubuntu. Sounds too simple!

Please let me know the proper approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if I can just wipe both hard drives clean, then reset my BIOS to recognize the 'new' drive setup, then start installing Ubuntu. Sounds too simple!

Yes, you can, IF your BIOS supports reordering the hard drives; mine does.

> What I would like to do is the following: 1. Transfer all my files to the Win 8 PC 2. Switch the 160 GB drive to be my C:drive and the 320 GB Drive to be my d:drive 3. install Ubuntu 12 on the 'new' c: drive and use the D: drive for files and programs

Why make the 160GB the "C" drive? Is it faster?

You can do a custom install, reconfiguring your filesystem to put /home and /opt (for somoe post-install apps) on the 320GB HD, but the apps which come with Linux will install to the first drive, and getting them to install to the second drive would require a lot of work.

Comment: I checked out the hard drives, both run at 7200 rpm but the smaller one (160gb) is rated better than the larger one. I've always been told to use the smaller drive for OS and larger drive for data. So that is why I want to switch the drives, assuming performance will be a little better also.

Comment: I checked my BIOS and I can change my HDD boot order so it looks like I can do what I want. I guess my last question would be whether, once Ubuntu is installed, I can wipe and reformat the 320 GB HD. I would think so. If anyone else has any suggestions or objections to what I'm planning please let me know, I would appreciate your comments.